# the same function as apply in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

For example, I want to compute to miss ratio for row and column,

```
apply(iris,1,function(x){sum(is.na(x))/nrow(iris) })
```

for row's miss ratio and

```
apply(iris,2,function(x){sum(is.na(x))/nrow(iris) })
```

for column's miss ratio

how can I do use data.table function to achieve the same result? `apply` is too slow for big data(6G size),but it is convenient,so I want to know whether there is a same function like `apply` in data.table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
irs<-data.table(iris)
```

for row's miss ratio

```
irs[, rowSums(is.na(irs))/nrow(irs)][]
```

for column's miss ratio

```
irs[, colSums(is.na(irs))/nrow(irs)][]
```